# Como fazer um GIF ficar em loop enquanto a próxima cena carrega

Tags: unity3d

Olá, eu procurei alguns tópicos na internet, mas nada fazia exatamente o que eu queria, e meu pouco conhecimento em Unity não me permite adaptar os códigos.

Eu tenho uma Cena `GUI` que tem um botão `Começar`. Quando o botão for pressionado, ele vai chamar a Cena `Game`. Porém enquanto a cena `Game` é carregada, gostaria de fazer um tela preta com um GIF rodando em loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d não suporta GUIFS, mas você pode trocar o sprite de uma imagem repetidamente para dar uma ilusão de GIF, é meio complexo, mas tem como carregar sua cena ao mesmo tempo do seu GIF